# How to find the number of unique words in array list

Tags: java

So I am trying to create an for loop to find unique elements in a `ArrayList`.
I already have a `ArrayList` stored with user input of 20 places (repeats are allowed) but I am stuck on how to count the number of different places inputted in the list excluding duplicates. (i would like to avoid using hash)

Input:

```
[park, park, sea, beach, town]
```

Output:

```
[Number of unique places = 4]
```

Heres a rough example of the code I'm trying to make:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  ArrayList<City> place = new ArrayList();
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

  for(...) {  // this is just to receive 20 inputs from users using the scanner
    ...
  }

# This is where i am lost on creating a for loop...

}
```

Comment: Why on earth would you want to avoid using a hash set? That's by far the easiest and probably the most efficient way of dealing with this problem.

Comment: Haha yeah i know but i looked it up before and  i tried it but i don't really understand how to use hash very clearly yet. So i i were to use it and summit the script i doubt i can explain clearly on how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way that comes to mind (without using `Set` or hashvalues) is to make a second list.

```
ArrayList<City> places = new ArrayList<>();
//Fill array

ArrayList<String> uniquePlaces = new ArrayList<>();
for (City city : places){
    if (!uniquePlaces.contains(city.getPlace())){
        uniquePlaces.add(city.getPlace());
    }
}

//number of unique places:
int uniqueCount = uniquePlaces.size();
```

Note that this is not super efficient =D

Comment: Ok this is what i was missing making a second list thanks! Now i can compare 2 list using a nested for loop with a if condition.

Comment: @brand - No, don't use a nested loop. Just use the `contains()` method of `List`; it already has the loop coded for you and packaged up in a nice method.

Answer (score 4):

you can use a Set for that. 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html

Store the list data to the `Set`.`Set` will not have duplicates in it, so the size of set will be the elements without duplicates.

use this method to get the set size.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#size()

Sample Code.

```
        List<String> citiesWithDuplicates =
                Arrays.asList(new String[] {"park", "park", "sea", "beach", "town"});
        Set<String> cities = new HashSet<>(citiesWithDuplicates);

        System.out.println("Number of unique places = " + cities.size());
```

Comment: Maybe a map is the best structure for this problem, but even so you should at least give some implementation details if you want to answer.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Why would a map be better than a set?

Comment: @TedHopp Then why did you suggest using a `HashSet` above?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - I don't understand your question. I suggested a `HashSet` because that's a concrete implementation of `Set`. That has nothing to do with a `Map`. I just wanted to know your thinking about why a `Map` is better than a `Set`. Or am I misreading your comment?

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to use Java 8, you can use the `distinct` method of Java streams:

```
int numOfUniquePlaces = list.stream().distinct().count();
```

Otherwise, using a set is the easiest solution. Since you don't want to use "hash", use a `TreeSet` (although `HashSet` is in most cases the better solution). If that is not an option either, you'll have to manually check for each element whether it's a duplicate or not.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use implementations of `Set` or `Map` interfaces (that would solve you problem with one line of code) and you want to stuck with `ArrayList`, I suggest use something like `Collections.sort()` method. It will sort you elements. Then iterate through the sorted array and compare and count duplicates. This trick can make solving your iteration problem easier.

Anyway, I strongly recommend using one of the implementations of `Set` interface.

Answer (score 0):

Use following answer. This will add last duplicate element in distinct list if there are multiple duplicate elements.

```
List<String> citiesWithDuplicates = Arrays.asList(new String[] {
                "park", "park", "sea", "beach", "town", "park", "beach" });
        List<String> distinctCities = new ArrayList<String>();

        int currentIndex = 0;

        for (String city : citiesWithDuplicates) {
            int index = citiesWithDuplicates.lastIndexOf(city);
            if (index == currentIndex) {
                distinctCities.add(city);
            }
            currentIndex++;
        }
            System.out.println("[ Number of unique places =  "
            + distinctCities.size() + "]");
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you do not want to use any HashSets or similar options, a quick and dirty nested for-loop like this for example does the trick (it is just slow as hell if you have a lot of items (20 would be just fine)):

```
int differentCount=0;
for(City city1 : place){
    boolean same=false;
    for(City city2 : place){
       if(city1.equals(city2)){
         same=true;
         break;
       }
    }
    if(!same)
      differentCount++;
}
System.out.printf("Number of unique places = %d\n",differentCount);
```

Comment: Yeah its kinda slow but it solves the problem with the creating 2nd list idea and a nested loop it worked thanks